# Who are these bunny girls from Gurren Lagann referencing?

Tags: gurren-lagann

I stumbled over this scene from Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann (EP6) again and realized it contains a lot more references than I initially realized.

The bunny girls seem to reference characters from other Gainax shows. I recgonize some of them as listed below, but for some I have no idea. I'm also not sure which ones are references at all and which ones are just generic; maybe I labelled too many. The labels are consistent over all pictures.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

1. [Nono (*Diebuster*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/2058/Nono)
2. [Asuka (*Neon Genesis Evangelion*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/94/Asuka_Langley_Soryu)
3. [Lal'C (*Diebuster*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/3887/LalC_Melk_Mark)
4. [Mahoro (*Mahoromatic*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/1314/Mahoro_Ando) **thanks ʞɹɐzǝɹ and Jon Lin**
5. [Rei (*Neon Genesis Evangelion*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/86/Rei_Ayanami)
6. Probably [Anna (*He is my master*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/1815/Anna_Kurauchi) **thanks Jon Lin**
7. [Aki (*Abenobashi*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/265/Aki) **thanks ʞɹɐzǝɹ and Jon Lin**
8. [Reiko (*Gunbuster*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/15946/Reiko_Kashiwara) **thanks Jon Lin**
9. [Jung (*Gunbuster*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/3886/Jung_Freud)
10. **?**
11. [Misato (*Neon Genesis Evangelion*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/1259/Misato_Katsuragi)
12. Maybe [Owner (*Ebichu*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/6691/Owner) or [Yukino (*His and Her Circumstances*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/357/Yukino_Miyazawa) **thanks Jon Lin**
13. A second Jung?
14. Maybe [Izumi (*He is my master*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/1813/Izumi_Sawatari) or [Miyuki (*Mahoromatic*)](http://myanimelist.net/character/1319/Miyuki_Sakura) **thanks Jon Lin**

Comment: 4 is Mahoro from *Mahoromatic*.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Thanks! Guess I didn't find her, because it's a joint between Gainax and Shaft.

Comment: 7 is Ms. Aki from *Abenobashi*.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ haha, indeed, thanks again. 4 and 7 are the two I surely expected to be non-generic because they were so prominently shown. The rest I might be willing to accept as portraying no one in particular. Then again, 8 has this distinctive hair clip,  maybe I'll go look again myself.

Comment: That's the most excited-looking Rei I've ever seen... and the bustiest Asuka...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse yeah, Rei is frighteningly out of character. The boobs are pretty uniform, I guess they wanted to be fair ;) The scene also has some serious gainaxing. That would've been difficult for some, if they kept the canon sizes.

Comment: @mivilar maybe not, remember there is a Rei who's far more social than the regular one. we see her at the end of the original Evangelion Anime where we see that alternate universe where Shinji and Asuka are siblings and there's no Evas

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- 4 is [Mahoro Ando](http://myanimelist.net/character/1314/Mahoro_Ando) from Mahoromatic
- 6, [Anna Kurauchi](http://myanimelist.net/character/1815/Anna_Kurauchi) (He is my Master) is the only prominent GAINAX character I know with that color hair and hairstyle
- 7 is [Aki](http://myanimelist.net/character/265/Aki) from Abenobashi
- 8 is [Reiko Kashiwara](http://myanimelist.net/character/15946/Reiko_Kashiwara) from Gunbuster
- 10 ???
- 12 possibly the "Owner" from Ebichu or [Yukino](http://myanimelist.net/character/357/Yukino_Miyazawa) from His and Her Circumstances because she sometimes wears her hair that way
- 14 possibly [Sakura Miyuki](http://ami.animecharactersdatabase.com/uploads/chars/thumbs/200/9180-2064304184.jpg) from Mahoromatic?

Most likely they're just random girls as there's really nothing that can accurately identify them like clothing or eye color.

Comment: Thanks! I added the info above. Do you happen to have a picture of Yukino with her hair that far back? I couldn't really find one (Maybe [this?](http://img860.imageshack.us/img860/6799/ywchmhnpfdvg3mk9nhl.png)).

In any case, I agree that many might be random girls. I'll leave this running for a bit longer but if no one else jumps in I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @mivilar Well, ones similar to that, where she's got her bangs kind of pulled back with a hair band.